# Updating a user model attribute through a Devise session login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using the Devise authentication gem for a Ruby on Rails app.  When a user logs in by creating a new session I would like to update a column in my user model.  What would be the best way to do this?

Is there any way to have a hidden field that updates the model?

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <% f.hidden_field :field_a, :value => 'test' %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting Devise::SessionsController create method. When the user login it will just authenticate the user, it wont update user record. So there is no use of keeping the hidden field in the form

Try like this

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
 #do your update here
end

end
```

or else you can follow this link http://denmarkin.tumblr.com/post/5194645960/how-to-overwrite-devise-sessions-controller-in-rails-3

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution. My route is:  `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => :sessions }` and I have a `sessions_controller.rb` and I have also created a sessions folder in my views. In the new sessions folder I changed the text to see if it was correctly working.  The new sessions view appears correctly, however when I try to login I get a routing error: `Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/sign_in.user"` Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are using "class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController", if so please change that to "class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController"